# Magento- How to config a Product with different sizes, materials and prices

Tags: magento

I need to find the best method to configure a product which has multiple materials, sizes and prices. I tried making attribute sets with custom material and sizes, but after adding the 3rd size and prices, I loose the pricing structure.

Briefly this is how it should look:

Product Sign 1 - the default material, size and price is Silver Sign, 10x10, and it's 5.00.

(These are simple/associated products)

```
Product Sign 1

Material       Size        Price
Silver Sign    10x10        5.00
Gold Sign      10x10        10.00
Bronze Sign    10x10        15.00
Silver Sign    12x12        5.75
Gold Sign      12x12        10.75
Bronze Sign    12x12        15.75
Silver Sign    18x18        25.75
Gold Sign      18x18        20.75
Bronze Sign    18x18        25.75
```

Any help or thoughts on how to best set make this work is appreciated.
1.7 CE